# c++ registration and sign in program help needed

Tags: c++, logging

okay, so I'm getting two errors.

1. invalid pointer addition [in the (username+".txt" lines)]
2. function getline should have a prototype.

Here's the code, I'm making registration/sign up/sign in form. Will be adding a little more functionality to it later on, e.g. **** format for password and restriction for password too. as of now, I'm stuck here and don't know how to proceed. Moreover I'm being forced to use turbo c++ because school :))))). 
Please do suggest some good compilers too for MacOSX.
Thanks!

```
    #include<iostream.h>
    #include<fstream.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    void register_user();
    void login_user();
    void main_menu();

    int IsLoggedIn()
    {
        char username[20],password[20],un[20],pw[20];
        cout<<"Enter Username: ";gets(username);
        cout<<"Enter Password: ";gets(password);

        ifstream read(username + ".txt");
        getline(un,read);
        getline(pw,read);

        if(un==username && pw==password)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    void main()
    {
        main_menu();
    }

    void main_menu()
    {
        int choice;
        cout<<"1. Register\n2. Login\nYour Choice: "; cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: register_user(); break;
            case 2: login_user(); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    void register_user()
    {
        char username[20], password1[20],password2[20];
        cout<<"Enter Username: ";gets(username);
        rev1:cout<<"Enter Password: ";gets(password1);
        cout<<"Enter Password again: ";gets(password2);
        while (password1!=password2)
        {
            goto rev1;
        }
        ofstream file;
        file.open(username + ".txt");
        file<<username<<endl<<password1;
        file.close();
    }

    void login_user()
    {
        int chk=IsLoggedIn();
        if(chk==1)
        {
            cout<<"Log in successfull!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Log in unsucessfull!\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `std::string` rather than `char []`. Also `#include<iostream.h>` isn't standard c++. Are you using Turbo C++?

Comment: yeah bro, i mentioned it above :P

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you are going to use `goto`, common practice is to place the label on its own, separate line (so it is easier to find).

Comment: You may want to use nested loops instead of `goto`.  Search the internet for "spaghetti code goto".

Comment: Also, use `fgets` with strings, so you can prevent **buffer overflow**.  For example, a User enters text with 30 characters.  What happens?  Search the internet for "why is gets bad".

Answer (score 1):

You can't use operator '+' for C-Style strings.

You will need to use `strcat()` or `snprintf`.

Also, use either `fscanf` or `fread` or `fgets` for reading into character arrays.

You can't use operator `==` on C-Style strings (character arrays), use `strcmp`.  The `operator ==` will be comparing the values in pointers, not the text pointed to.

If you are going to use C-Style strings, I highly recommend you review the `str*()` family of functions.